# How was Adobe Acrobat 9 made?

Tags: language-design, acrobat

Can anyone tell how Adobe Acrobat 9 was made? I like the look and feel of the GUI and I'm curious how it was made. Specifically, what programming language was used to make it?

Answer (score 9):

All of Adobe's major products are written in C++.  Although they're mostly written using proprietary toolkits, Adobe has actually open-sourced some of their common low-level libraries.  You can read more about them, and download them yourself, at [Adobe's Software and Technology Lab (STLab)](http://stlab.adobe.com/).  One of their libraries, [Adam and Eve](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__asl__overview.html#asl_overview_adam_and_eve_architecture), I find especially interesting and generally useful.

Comment: You mean you have used Adam & Eve in your own projects? Wasn't it hard to integrate their codebase with your own code?

Comment: I have not used Adam and Eve in any commercial product; just for tinkering around.  In that context, integrating into a code base wasn't an issue, since the only code base I had was that one.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was programmed in C++ using the Evil framework.